# Limiting the scope of a static member to n specific classes

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++builder

how to limit the scope of a static member to a n specific classes? for example if i create a1 object of class A and a2 object of class A, i want these objects(a1, a2 created with A) could have different values for their static member but the same for their corresponding derived classes.

```
  class A{
    public:
           A(int member){
               A::mMember=member;}
           void set(int member){
               A::mMember=member;}
           int get(){
               return A::mMember;}
        protected:
           static int mMember;
    };

    int A::mMember;

    class B:public A{
    public:
        B(int member):A(member){};
    };

    class C:public A{

        C(int member):A(member){};

    };

    int main()
    {   

      A * a1= new A(1);
         std::cout<<"a1: "<< a1->get()<<std::endl;
         B * b1= new B(2);
         std::cout<<"a1: "<< a1->get()<<std::endl;

         // How to make a1 continue be a1=2 and a2 = 5. I mean how to limit a static member     
         //to  only its derivated class
         A * a2 = new A(5);
         std::cout<<"a1: "<< a1->get()<<std::endl;
         std::cout<<"a2: "<< a2->get()<<std::endl;

    }
```

Comment: Please write a proper question. Don't put the whole of the question inside a single comment in a large chunk of code.

Comment: Why don't you just use a non-static member variable?

Comment: I have a map member in base class, when the derived class is constructed, the derive class assign the same  id to a map because it inherits that member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of a static member is that it's "one for everywhere" [not without limits, but let's ignore that for the purpose of this question].

In your example code it seems like you want `b1 = B(2)` to alter the A value, but `a2` to have a new value for `mMember`. This is not possible using a static member.

To me, it seems like what you really want is either a factory function that knows when you need a new object and when you don't, and passes a reference to this object in the relevant constructor, or some sort of storage (through a static member function in A).

In the first case, that would look a bit like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
       A(int member, int &ref_member) : mref_member = ref_member
       {
           A::mMember=member;
       }
       void set(int member)
       {
           A::mMember=member;
       }
       int get(){
           return A::mMember;
       }
    protected:
       static int mMember;
};

int A::mMember;

class B : public A
{
    public:
        B(int member, int &ref_member) : A(member,ref_member)
        {
        };
};


A* maker(int v, bool needs_new_ref, char type)
{
     static int *ref = NULL;
     if (needs_new_ref || !ref)
     {
        ref = new int;
     } 
     switch(type)
     {
         case 'A':
             return new A(v, ref);
             break;
         case 'B':
             return new B(v, ref);
             break;
     }
 }
```

The second alternative involves a function like this:

```
 int& ref(int id)
 {
    static map<int, int> refs;
    return refs[id];
 }
```

Then call `ref(id)` when you need the reference. You need to figure out a way to generate "id's" for this one.

Depending on exactly you want to achieve, there may be a lot of other solutions. I'm pretty certain your question is an XY question - you are asking how to do Y because you think that is the right way to achieve X.

Comment: +1 for "*I'm pretty certain your question is an XY question*".